# Resources assembly not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to create unit tests for my MVC5 app and I'm using Resources. My problem is that when I execute the test it throws this exception.

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Unable to find appropriate resources for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Resources.Ressources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked to the assembly "GestionSaisieExternaliséeV2" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed

I'm using Resources in the action of the controller.

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
{
     get
     {
          if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null))
          {
               global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.Ressources", typeof(Ressources).Assembly);
               resourceMan = temp;
          }
          return resourceMan;
     }
}
```

the VS Solution project:

- MVC 5 project.
- unit test project.

Comment: Did you verify all things mentioned in the error message? If yes - make sure to update your post with your findings.

Comment: I dont know exactly what to verify, my resources file ".resx" is the bin folder and the dll for the MVC app also.

Comment: Are you missing a reference in your test project?

Comment: Please, if you found solution - please either post as complete answer (and accept it at some point) OR close the question.

Comment: No reference missing in my test project.

Comment: Looks like you've misspelled `"Resources.Ressources"` (note the two `s`es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
The resources file should be set as "Embedded Resource" in the properties of the file.

Thanks to All of you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your resources class public; see the picture below:

[image: Make resources public.]

Another thing would be to add [`InternalVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of your MVC project. This will make the internal types (the default access modifier) visible to the test assembly hence you'll be able to access `Resources.Something` from there.